# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' when inserting data using mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

The following program collects the users inputs and stores them, then it saves that data to a .csv or emails it to me, then finally it inserts that data into a MySQL database.

I am using mysql.connector for this, however I am getting the error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

when the program executes.

Here is the code, I think the problem is to do with the type of data trying to be inserted into the database, but I cannot be sure.

```
import mysql.connector

# ...

# Connect to MySQL Database and send user_input data to 'user' TABLE.
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='ash123', host='localhost', database='user_data_db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("INSERT INTO user (user_id, first_name, last_name, age, postcode,  email_address)"
         "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (user_id, firstname, lastname, age, postcode, email)) 

cursor.execute(query)
print("Executed Successfully")

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's of the `bytes` or `bytearray` type, `cursor.execute` expects the first argument (SQL query) to have the `encode` method. `query` is a 2-tuple, tuples do not have that method and attempts to access it fail with `AttributeError`.

You can unpack `query`, in order to use its elements as positional arguments for `cursor.execute`:

```
cursor.execute(*query)
# = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user (user_id, first_name, last_name, age, postcode, email_address)"
#                  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (user_id, firstname, lastname, age, postcode, email))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have made the changes and it works perfectly. Such a small changes makes all the difference. I will look into this in the future! :)